# [tag:Eclipse]: Running an C++ app in a remote shell which is already opened

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging, eclipse-cdt

What I would like to do is to start a Remote Shell in Eclipse, run a perl script in this shell and configure Eclipse Run and Debug Configurations to always use that particular shell to run/debug the app.

For information my perl script telnets to a test board, mounts a folder from the network onto the board and sets up few environment variables. One of the problem is that all the information to mount the folder and to set up the environment variables are on the build machine and not on the board (otherwise I would run a script directly on the test board).

Any help or suggestion would greatly appreciated.

Manu